# converting numbers from base 10 to base 4

Tags: python, radix

I already asked similar question about this but that only for list of number from 0 to 15. i thought what about trying to convert numbers from 0 to more than 15.Here is what I wrote so far

```
def base_convert(i, b):
   result = []
   for i in range(20):
          while i > 0:
                 result.insert(0, i % b)
                 i = i // b
          return result

print(base_convert(i,4))
```

but I got error saying that name 'i' is not defined. Did I missed something here? Or maybe I wrote a wrong code. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: `print(base_convert(i,4))` You haven't defined `i` when you call the function.

Comment: hint: remember that base 4 is 1/2 of octal, so 027 = 2*8 + 7*0

Comment: did the answer below solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help, please let me know so that I can delete it to save people from wasting their time looking at it.

Comment: I already got it work with similar code you wrote. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Great, it is good to know that you solve your problem, it is the goal of S.O. : getting answers to questions. One more step to go is to post your answer here and accept it. This will definitely help anyone with similar problem. And if the answer bellow is close enough and you do not want to put your solution here, you can also accept this one by clicking the accept check mark beside it.

Comment: I'll give you the real reason you are having trouble. You are using `python` for this and not `ANSI C`.

Answer (score 3):

Three problems:

1. You haven't defined `i` when you call the function as mentionned by Morgan
2. `i` is an input arg so you should not override it in the function before using it.
3. You do not need the `for` loop.

It should look like the following with the test for 9

```
def base_convert(i, b):
    result = []
    while i > 0:
            result.insert(0, i % b)
            i = i // b
    return result

print(base_convert(9,4)
```